# Can someone explain to me how to get the time complexity and how to resolve the inner loop issue

Tags: time-complexity

```
def something(n)
   for I in range(50):
      for j in range (n/2):
         for k in range n/(j+1):
            do constant work()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first loop runs a constant `50` times. The inner loop runs `n/2` times. So far we're at O(50n/2), but big O doesn't care about constant factors, so this runs in time linear to `n`, so O(n).

Knowing this we can remove a level of loop to make this easier to digest.

```
def something(n)
   for j in range (n/2):
      for k in range n/(j+1):
         do constant work()
```

The inner loop is the interesting one.

| j | times to run loop |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | n/1 = n |
| 1 | n/2 |
| 2 | n/3 |
| ... | ... |
| j | n/j |

When we sum this series, we get n * log n.

Comment: for some reason the answer is O(n) which is making me very confused. Otherwise I think what you did is right and also what I thought of

Comment: @VictorChen It's not O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The running time is: n + n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/(n/2) .

This is bound by the equation n/2 + n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/n .

Which equals n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n).

1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n is the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Growth_rate) H(n) and it has a logarithmic growth log(e)n . log(e)n in turn is bound by log(2)n

[image]

Therefore our running time is O (nlogn)

I've posted a question about the sequence here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4489790/772035

Answer (score 0):

> whats the summation: 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n.

The numbers

[image: Hn]

are called the [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). They grow like

[image: Hn]

so that

[image: y]

where γ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant).

And the running time is approximately

[image: T(n)]

Comment: The running time has to be one of the seven known running times. Either O(1), O(logn), O(n), O(nlogn), O(n^2), O(n^3), O(n!)

Comment: @Gilbert: You can always throw away knowledge and be less precise if you like.